# Ethernet won't come up until link status is toggled

Tags: ethernet, systemd-networkd

I am using systemd-networkd.  I was able to fix this issue by adding this in systemd-networkd.service:

```
ExecStartPost=bash -c 'ip link set dev eth0 down;ip link set dev eth0 up'
```

I would rather this were somehow added to my file /etc/systemd/network/20-wired.network file which configures eth0, but I do not know how.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this?  Note that if all I do is bring the link up, my Ethernet interface still fails.

Comment: This could actually be a bug in the driver for your network interface, or a compatibility issue between the network interface and the switch it's connected to. The latter chance might be noteworthy is one of the NIC/switch pair supports [Energy-Efficient Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy-Efficient_Ethernet) standards and the other doesn't.

Comment: Out of curiosity, only one interface? No overlapping LANs defined anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The Ethernet driver was misconfigured.

I read the driver documentation. The driver had the possibility of configuring a gpio phy-reset (the driver was in device tree).  When I configured phy-reset-gpios in device tree the issue went away.

But I still wonder if there is anything comparable in systemd-networkd to the /etc/network/interfaces options "pre-up", "post-up", "pre-down", "post-down" which can run arbitrary commands?